# Is there a voltage regulator IC that takes PWM input?

Tags: voltage-regulator, filter, pwm

I am looking for a small IC that provides a regulated dc voltage based on the duty cycle of the input. This is probably asking for a lot but does anyone know if one exists. Essentially I need a low pass filter but I need to conserve board space as much as possible as I am VERY limited. Also, I have done LPF's in the past with just a resistor and capacitor but I can never seem to get the noise out. I usually end up with at least 20mA of ripple. My PWM would likely be 3.3V pk-to-pk but I could also manage 5V as well. Any ideas?

Comment: What are the specifications on the output signal? It would be helpful to know the output voltage range, the maximum current load, and the maximum allowable voltage ripple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt such a device exists. A PWM signal as such is not a good start to generate a stable output voltage with as little ripple as possible. The regulator would require a filter with a rather large capacitor (I guess you want to draw some current from it), which will need to be external anyway. It wouldn't save you any space in any case.
If your PWM signal is to supply power, and not just a voltage, you'll have to provide a power driver, since PWM signals usually only provide a voltage.

Comment: The size of the capacitor would depend a lot on the PWM frame rate.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide any specs on how small you want to go but you could consider an op-amp as a voltage regulator with a small pass transistor and LPF for the reference. Or, you could look for programmable voltage regulators; these are usually SPI or I2C. If you have an adjustable regulator, consider a digital potentiometer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the regulator's voltage reference, you could use the PWM signal to lower the V_ref according to the PWM's duty cycle. Will be slow, because you will need a significant low pass filter, but it might work.